# External Script not reachable

Tags: javascript, error-handling, server, external, offline

I have an external script integrated on our homepage. Sometimes, the server for this script is offline. So I searched some way, when the server is offline, to show a jpeg instead of the script. I googled a long time for a solution but didn't find a clue that helps. Is there somebody out to give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

If the script is accessible over the internet, you can send an API request for it in your script and then check whether you get a response or not. 
In the latter case, you can show you jpeg.